# Mongodb query is executing slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mondodb collection

[image]

It contains around and 2000 rows and each `daily_details` array contains around 50 entries. I'm querying all the details for a given `daily_details.date` range but its running very slow. I tried creating index as well but no luck.

```
db.db_col_his_details.ensureIndex( { "daily_details.date": 1 } )
```

**Query**:

```
db.db_col_his_details.find({
     "daily_details.date": ISODate("2014-12-31 18:30:00.000Z")
}).explain()
```

I'm using Java morphia api to query.

**Explain Output:**

```
{
  "cursor": "BtreeCursor daily_details.date_1",
  "isMultiKey": true,
  "n": 1479,
  "nscannedObjects": 1479,
  "nscanned": 1479,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans": 1479,
  "nscannedAllPlans": 1479,
  "scanAndOrder": false,
  "indexOnly": false,
  "nYields": 0,
  "nChunkSkips": 0,
  "millis": 11,
  "indexBounds": {
    "daily_details.date": [
      [
        ISODate("2014-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
        ISODate("2014-12-31T18:30:00.000Z")
      ]
    ]
  },

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you execute the query from the mongo shell and add explain() to see the mongo query plan. this will help show if the index is getting used or not

Comment: I checked. Index is getting used in query.

Comment: can you provide the output of the explain query along with the actual query?  Also how slow is the query - what is the expected execution time for the query? What architecture is the mongo DB running on? performance related questions are always relative to what is fast/slow and what is acceptable...

Comment: @SagarVimal It would be very helpful if you could include all the details of what you have tried, including the query and the stats from the `explain()` method to show exactly how many miliseconds it took etc

Comment: Output: '{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor daily_details.date_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1479,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1479,
    "nscanned" : 1479,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1479,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1479,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 11,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "daily_details.date" : [ 
            [ 
                ISODate("2014-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2014-12-31T18:30:00.000Z")
            ]
        ]
    },  
}'

Comment: Query: 'db.db_col_his_details.find({"daily_details.date":ISODate("2014-12-31 18:30:00.000Z")}).explain()'. I'm using Java morphia api to query.

Comment: according to the explain output, it is only taking 11 milliseconds to execute the query which is quite fast.

Comment: are you running the query directly in the mongo shell or executing it from code? have you ruled out that the code is the bottleneck and not the DB? How are you measuring the performance of the query and what timings are you seeing?

Comment: Indexing is one part but as others have alluded to there are many more aspects to performance and optimization.Whereas your query is claimed to execute in 11 ms, I would emphasize sharing your topology for the forum to better assess your scenario. For example, sharding can provide improvements for targeted queries. Is it always executing in 11 ms or may you sometimes suffer from a read preference of primary while the primary is supporting inserts ? There are so many possibilities beyond doc model and your results initially point elsewhere.